# Inner Div 100% height outside of parent Div

Tags: css, html

[image: the main source of the problem, innder div 100% outside or perent div]

The reason this is happening obviously is because of the Gray box above. Now I have tried to use 97% but that don't work so well when you resize. I cannot use a static value as the outside div can change.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Without JavaScript. and if not possible with css then what the height:expresion(???); for it ?

Here the code i have so far by the way:

```
.outside_div {  
    width:227px;
    height:500px;
 }

.scrolabe_div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `bottom` attribute instead.

```
.outside_div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 227px;
    height: 500px;
}

.scrolabe_div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px; /* since the top doesn't change, fix it here */
    bottom: 10px; /* set this accordingly, probably 10px */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You sir are my new hero, Thank you. Please UP VOTE THIS GUY

Answer (score 2):

Remove the height from the scrollable div:

```
.scrolabe_div {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

When you specify a percentage based `height` or `width` the computed value is in relation to the parent container. If you remove the height definition on `.scrollable_div` then it will grow in `height` with relation to its content.

Comment: No. That prevents scrolling all together.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `height` from your css or style. the browser renders height of an inner element decides the length of outer one so specifying height is unnecessary

Comment: Prevents scrolling all together,